# Is Marshal.GetActiveObject a safe way to see if a specific version of Visual Studio is running?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I need to check if a specific version of Visual Studio is running. The solution I've come up with for now is the following

```
public bool IsRunning()
{
    object instance;

    try {
        instance = Marshal.GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE.11.0");
    } catch {
        instance = null;
    }

    return instance != null;
}
```

Is this a safe way to check for a specific version? If not what would a better way be?

Comment: I assume you're running as an Add-in or an extension? If so, what type?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it.  Do release the object.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I'm running a console app. I need to update some files that are locked when Visual Studio is open so to avoid returning an error I want to tell the user to make sure Visual Studio is closed

Comment: @HansPassant To release the object do I simply assign null to it?

Comment: You *might* want to investigate the [Restart Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373680(v=vs.85).aspx) (not a managed API). I believe that VS2012 interacts with this API correctly - it would be a far better user experience.